# How to remove a roller shade tube for installation?

Tags: repair, windows

I just moved in to a new place and need to install a set of roller shades that wasn't completed.

I have the roller and the mechanism attached to the wall is already in place screwed in. I just can't figure out how to remove the currently attached tube so that I can put the new one in.

Attached photos of both sides of the tube and attachment. Can anyone point out?

[image: Blackout shade]
[image: one side]
[image: release clutch]

Comment: I would say it is a twist lock mechanism. See the slotted groves under the roller mount? Twist it to loosen it

Comment: Worst case scenario: Unscrew the mounting brackets from the wall, remove them from the old tube, install them on the new tube, reinstall the brackets on the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a twist lock mechanisme.

See the two slots/groves.

Twist it till becomes loose

Not sure the function of the protruding leveler, try left or right or lifting it

[image: twist]